# How to store headers and cookies from python requests

Tags: python, authentication, cookies, python-requests, session-cookies

My propose is to login at my application through python requests. I was able to get a token, that is expected, but passing it by GET isn't enough. So, i want to store the request in a cookie, pass the token, and maybe the browser can login.

So, let's resume what i did (this is pseudo code)

```
    session = requests.Session()
    session.get('<url>salt')
    r = session.get('<url>login', params={username, password})
    r.headers['token']
```

I discovered this by looking the requests while login. The token is passed to the application after. So, how can i store the "r" as a cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply access your session cookie using:

```
client = requests.session()
cook = client.cookies
extracted_token_value = client.cookies['token']

#this will print your cookie and token
print cook.text 
print extracted_token_value

#updating your header now:
client.headers.update({'New Header': 'extracted_token_value')
```

BR